# How to init a NSMapTable with a value of block by swift

Tags: swift, closures, block

When i use `NSMapTable`, a trouble make me unhappy,I do

`[self.map setObject:block forKey:key]`

in obj-c is OK,But when I do

`map.setObject(block as! AnyObject, forKey: key)`

in Swift, I get an error

> Could not cast value of type '() -> ()' (0x15d9a604) to
>   'Swift.AnyObject' (0x15d7335c)

How can i fix it when used `NSMapTable`? I don't want to use `Dictionay` , because the key is complex.

Answer (score 3):

A block is not an object. Wrap your block in a class, then assign your block to the class as a property.

```
class MyClass {
   let block: Void -> Void
}

[self.map setObject:myClass forKey:key]
```